# algien me podria explicar este codigo, quiero conectar a una base de datos, para un buscador en android studio, pero no me conecta

Tags: php

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "Engineringg96";
    $dbname = "tbl_fish";

    try 
    {
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die("OOPs something went wrong");
    }

?>


<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "Engineringg96";
    $dbname = "tbl_fish";

    try 
    {
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die("OOPs something went wrong");
    }

?>
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: el titulo debe referenciar tu problema.. y tu problema estar descripto en la pregunta. e igual, ese codigo no conecta a una base de datos, es una definicion de errores

Answer (score 2):

Dado que el código no es realizado por ti, te recomiendo poner la fuente para así poder ver si hay más documentación de eso, por otro lado, veo que tienes capturadas las excepciones pero no se imprime con claridad el error:

```
 try 
{
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    var_dump("Error: ".$e->getMessage());die;  // Muestra el error que se produce
}
```

Así podrás saber cuál es el error que se obtiene y así corregirlo.

Acá está la documentación de la clase [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

Suerte.

Answer (score 0):

aqui un ejemplo

```
<?php
/**
 * Provee las constantes para conectarse a la base de datos
 * Mysql.
 */
define("HOSTNAME", "localhost");// Nombre del host
define("DATABASE", "tubd"); // Nombre de la base de datos
define("USERNAME", "root"); // Nombre del usuario
define("PASSWORD", "tupass"); // Nombre de la constraseña
$con = mysqli_connect(HOSTNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DATABASE) or die('Unable to Connect');
$tildes = $con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
?>
```